# How to fix 'variable is not constructor' error in discord.js node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

i'm experemeting with discord bot and tried to create record in database, but there's some troubles with it.

mongodb server is running and fully functioning.

there's two files.
first, with code of command:
https://sourceb.in/6834bfe20e.js
and second. with mongoose scheme:
https://sourceb.in/9f0c7858df.js
acrually, there's third file index file with command handler and 
librarys initializations, but that's does not participate in the error.

I expected to create a record in the database, but there's error what says:
'token is not constructor' in command file:13:19

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:**
Simply put, you're declaring a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) `token`, but also passing a [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter) named `token` into your callback. When you're attempting to construct a new object based on the constant, you're actually using the callback's `token` variable.

Take note of this example, which emits the same error with your setup:

```js
const token = class {
  constructor(guild) {
    this.guild = guild;
  }
};

console.log(new token('1234')); // Works fine.

function foo(token) {
  console.log(new token('1234')); // Throws error.
}

foo({ someOtherVar: true });
```

**Solution:**
A quick rename of your variable(s) will do. I'd suggest naming your const `tokenSchema` to avoid conflict (and confusion).